# How can i check if user has actually rated my app?

Tags: android

I have an android application where if user rates my app he get some tokens.I have three options in my application. Yes, no, remind me later. If user clicks Yes, he is directed to my application but suppose he visits the url and don't rate my app how can i come to know about it?

Comment: This question has been asked quite a few times here. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374058/detect-if-the-user-rated-the-app-in-android?rq=1), [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-android-market?rq=1), and [th*t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318700/how-to-know-if-a-specific-user-has-rated-a-android-app?rq=1), and seems like there is no legitimate ways to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't know for certain, likely because Google is looking to keep developers from buying high ratings from their users with in-app items.

What you could do, which wouldn't give you 100% accuracy by any means, is have a server check your developer console over the course of the next couple minutes using the [developers console API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) and if the number of ratings increases, send a response to the app telling it to credit the user. But that would only work if your application has a sufficiently small number of users rating it, enough that you wouldn't get any overlap.